# Different line-height on iphone using font-face

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari, font-face, css

To vertically center my text in a box I use the same line-height as the height of the box. It works perfect on the iphone for system fonts. 
But when I use @font-face I have to ad at least 3px to the line-height for the iphone or otherwise the text isn't vertically centered anymore (it's up or 3px).

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding to the CSS:

```
myel {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. And I already tried different fonts. It's always the same effect.

Comment: Does there a only mobile safari hack exist? Since I found no answer to this searching google for hours now I guess this would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**

The Problem is that I was still on OS 3.1.3 on my 3G cause I made terrible experience on the perfomance using 4.2.

Whatever, **updating to the latest OS** 4.2 solves the line-height problem on fonts used with font-face in Mobile Safari.

Comment: Sadly I'm experiencing this problem between Safari for the mac and Safari for windows - on windows the text position is what I'd expect - on the mac nothing I've tried will vertically center the text except adding top padding to the element (which of course requires a hack because otherwise it looks weird on windows and other browsers.)

Comment: Even with the latest update on both machines? This is happen to be very strange. After all I started using different padding hacks to get it pixelperfect on every machine. So in the end it somehow depends on what you trying to achieve pixel perfect. But for sure I would be glad to know if there is an overall solution to this problem.